# How can i create foreign table with a condition

Tags: database, postgresql, database-administration

I have a table in other server for which I have to generate a foreign reference, but I don`t need all the data, I want to pull data based on a condition.

and also every time I query the foreign table it is going to actual table and fetching the data. how can I avoid that?

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createforeigntable.html

How to write the script

Comment: If you use PostreSQL, why did you tag the question with the Oracle tag?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to go get the data each time, then it sounds like you want a materialized view defined over a foreign table.